# How do I close an Android alertdialog

Tags: android

I am developing a quiz and I need the user to answer all the questions before proceeding.  When the user has not answered all the questions I display a simple alertdialog informing him or her. The problem is whatever I do I can't get the alertdialog to close.  Why isn't dialog.cancel working?`This is the code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
ad.setTitle("Unanswered Questions");  
ad.setMessage("You have not answered all the questions.");   
ad.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {  
     dialog.cancel(); 
}  
});  
ad.show();
```

Comment: Wrap your code in code tags so the question is readable.

Comment: that should work. May I suggest you try debugging each step and see if the ad.show() is being called. Oh and the onClick method too.

Answer (score 90):

The `AlertDialog.Builder` itself does not contain a `dismiss()` or `cancel()` method.

It is a convenience class to help you create a Dialog, which **DOES** have access to those methods.

Here is an example:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

alert.show();
```

You can then call the `alert.cancel()` method on the alert (not the builder).

Comment: how can you use alert on a click listener when it's still being built with the builder... please explain

Comment: My Java is a bit rusty but you'd have to create the AlertDialog object first and THEN call the setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener) on the AlertDialog object.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setButton%28int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29

Comment: The code in the answer above simply works. Should be the correct answer

Comment: The key is the event method has the dialog passed as a parameter, so even though you have not created it yet, when the even happens, you will have a valid dialog object.

Comment: Place `AlertDialog alert;` at the beginning of your activity in your declarations. Then at the very end of the code where you've created your AlertDialog, use: `alert = builder.create(); alert.show();` This will allow you from anywhere in your Activity to use `alert.cancel();` or `alert.dismiss();` to remove the AlertDialog from view.

Comment: this is perfect and great solution

Comment: when you implement your button cllick listener - you already have a callback with dialog parametr: 
builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel)) { dialog, which ->
            dialog.cancel()
        }

Answer (score 32):

try using

`dialog.dismiss()`

instead of using

`dialog.cancel()`

Comment: Hi Thanks for the replies.  I've already tried dialog.dismiss(), and that doesn't work either.  So I guess I'll have to try achie's suggestion of debugging each step as it looks as if my code is correct.

Comment: dismiss() isn't available for an AlertDialog, only for regular dialogs

Answer (score 11):

put this line in OnCreate()

```
Context mcontext = this;
```

and them use this variable in following code

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext);
alert.setTitle(title);
alert.setMessage(description);
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
alert.show();
```

Try this code.. It is running successfully..

Answer (score 11):

Use setNegative button, no Positive button required! I promise you'll win x

Answer (score 6):

```
AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
ad.setTitle("Unanswered Questions");  
ad.setMessage("You have not answered all the questions.");   
ad.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {  
     dialog.dismiss(); 
}  
});  
ad.show();
```

Answer (score 5):

Replying to an old post but hopefully somebody might find this useful. Do this instead

```
final AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
```

You can then go ahead and do,

```
builder.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
AlertDialog alert = builder.create(); 
alert.show();
```

The above code works but make sure you make `alert` a global variable so you can reach it from within the onClick method.

Comment: There is no need for a global variable to remember the dialog. You get it back as first argument in the onclick method.

Comment: Needed, if you want to dismiss it somewhere ELSE. THIS IS THE RIGHT WAY, specially with implements AlertDialog.OnClickListener

Answer (score 2):

Use Dialog instead of AlertDialog

AlertDialog doesn't have `dismiss()` but AlertDialog has some methods for button like `setPositiveButton()`.

I recommend to use Dialog if you want customized dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone was looking for the Kotlin version of this, it is as follows:

```
alertDialog.setPositiveButton(resources.getString(R.string.split_okay)) { 
    dialog, _ ->
        dialog.dismiss()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try putting a

```
Log.e("SOMETAG", "dialog button was clicked");
```

before the dialog.dismiss() line in your code to see if it actually reaches that section.

Answer (score 1):

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext);
alert.setTitle(title);
alert.setMessage(description);
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  @Override                                 
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
        cancelDialog(); //Implement method for canceling dialog
         }
   });
alert.show();
void cancelDialog()
{
   //Now you can either use  
   dialog.cancel();
    //or dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply restart the activity where your alertdialog appear or another activity depend on your judgement.
if you want to restart activity
use this
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());

Answer (score 0):

```
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("SAVE",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        /*Write your code here */
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.This answer might need little more explanation for fellow programmers to  understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution of PowerAktar, but the AlertDialog and the Builder always kept seperate parts. So how to get the "true" AlertDialog?

I found my solutions in the show-Dialog: You write

```
ad.show();
```

to display the dialog. In the help of show it says "Creates a AlertDialog with the arguments supplied to this builder and Dialog.show()'s the dialog." So the dialog is finally created here. The result of the show()-Command is the AlertDialog itself. So you can use this result:

```
AlertDialog adTrueDialog;
adTrueDialog = ad.show();
```

With this adTrueDialog it is possible to cancel() ...

```
adTrueDialog.cancel()
```

or to execute a buttons command within the dialog:

```
Button buttonPositive = adTrueDialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
buttonPositive.performClick();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
ad.setTitle("Unanswered Questions");  
ad.setMessage("You have not answered all the questions.");   
ad.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {  
     dialog.cancel(); 
}  
});
ad.create()
ad.show();
```

You didn't use `ad.create()` before `ad.show();`

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -2):

If you already use positive and negative button (like I do in my project) you can use Neutral Button to close the dialog.

I also noticed that in Android version >5 the dialog is closed by clicking outside of dialog window but in older version this is not happening.

```
ad.setNeutralButton("CLOSE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // close dialog
    }
});
```

Comment: Wrong, `.setCancelable(bool)` is used to define the behavior of clicking outside the window.

Comment: @M.Haché  whats wrong in saying that I noticed something ??  I haven't said that it's mandatory behavior. I just tested on two different devices with different OS....

Comment: There is nothing wrong in sharing something you've experienced. However, what you've written is misleading and could have been improved with the help of a quick google search.