# How to dismiss alertDialog manually?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to fetch some data from server.If this gets failed in the middle due to some reasons, I am displaying an alert prompting user to restart their download once again. So what I have done is, in the alert dialog's ok button I have called the download method once again. This makes the alert Dialog to freeze and stops it form hiding. Only when the download is completed the alert dialog gets dismissed. Can anyone suggest some idea here.

Comment: Please add some code example. I think you should first close the dialog and then start the download. Not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

in the onclick event dismiss the dialog first (dialog.cancel(); or dialog.dismiss()
)and then call the the download function again .
use this code to get the dialog showDialog(0);

```
  protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); //builder to create dialog

    switch(id)
    {
    case 0:

        if(GAME_STARTED)
        {
            builder.setTitle("failed");
            builder.setMessage("xxxxx");

            //The buttons set for the dialog box
            builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    builder.dismiss();
                                     download_again();
                }});


        }
        break;
default:
    }
    return builder.create();    
}
```

Comment: This is not custom dialog. It's an AlertDialog. there is no method like cancel() or dismiss().

Comment: see this    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336470/how-do-i-close-an-android-alertdialog